# I get 'Invalid Product! (missing native value)' in nativescript

Tags: in-app-purchase, nativescript, app-store-connect, nativescript-vue

I get `'Invalid Product! (missing native value)'` when I use the `purchase.getProducts()` method.

I have made a product in iTunes Connect and when I try to get it I get that error. I use the [nativescript-purchase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-purchase) plugin.

```js
purchase() {
  purchase.getProducts()
          .then((res) => { console.log(res); })
          .catch((e) => { console.log(e); })
},
```

Comment: Have you configured the products in your apple connect account? Did you update your app capabilities?

Comment: @Manoj yes, i have added a product in itunes connect and everything is correct there, same id as in package.json and so on..

Comment: What do you mean with " update your app capabilities? " I have used the correct code and imported everything i need and i do a ìnit()`before that method is fired also. And i just get a empty array, it says the length is 0

Comment: I think he means to ensure your app id is off the "explicit type", which has "in app purchases" enabled in the capabilities list. Did you get to the bottom of the issue?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the tutorial again I found this paragraph that solved this error code for me.

> You might NOT be able to see the registered products (consumable, non-consumable, etc.) if you do not have any contracts in effect regarding paid applications. To solve the problem, you can activate the contract for paid applications in App Store Connect > Contracts, Tax and Banking section.